# Vue - Change root component using Vue.componet or Async component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I want to have a dynamic/async component which will be loaded based on menu click. There will be a lot of links and components.

My problem is :

1. Cannot find test-component even I registered globally using Vue.Component
2. Can the component1 in root be changed? If it is possible, I will call component file using Ajax.

Thanks in advance.

Index.html

```
<script src="~/bundle/site.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <input type="button" v-on:click="changeComponent('test-component')" value="Click me"/>
    <component v-bind:is="view"></component>
</div>
```

site.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

global.Vue = Vue;
global.axios = axios;


var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        view: 'component1'
    },
    components: {
        'component1': {
            template: '<div>Dynamic Component master</div>'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        changeComponent: function (parComp) {
            this.component1 = parComp;
        },
    }
});


Vue.component('test-component', {
    template: '<div v-on:click = "changeName()"><h1>{{msg}}</h1></div>',
    data: function () {
        return {
            msg: "Test Componet"
        }
    },
    methods: {
        changeName: function () {
            this.msg = "mouse clicked";
        },
    }
})
```

> Update

1. change vm = new Vue().... to global.vm = new Vue().....
2. call vm.changeComponent('test-component')

It works now.

[image: Compoents have been created. How can I access these components outside Vue instance?]

Vue.options.components["test-component"] can access it.
But `test-component` cannot be access in html like :

```
<test-component></test-component>
```

Comment: You are trying to use Vue-specific constructions inside your `index.html` - but the browser does not recognize them. You should either switch to using Single-File components and Webpack bundler, or move your root Vue template outside of `<div id="app">` and into a dedicated `<template id="myName">`

Comment: Thanks Ivo Gelov.  Actually, I am using Webpack and site.js as entry point. I am not understand how to move root Vue template outside <div id="app">.  I have tried and find that the root template will not be rendered.

Comment: You can simply use Vue CLI to create a new empty project - then your root Vue instance will be created in `src/main.js` and your outermost component will be contained in `App.vue`

Comment: Thanks. But my project is not purely Vue and I am not using Vue CLI.

Comment: For question 2, the changeComponent() can be called directly like this vm.changeComponent('test-component'). –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by :

1. change vm = new Vue().... to global.vm = new Vue().....
2. declare Vue.component('test-component'.... before new Vue()

Thanks
Wilson